# Recommended way of checking only one running service?

Tags: shell-script, services, portability

I am writing a shell script to check if mongod server is running and if not, to start it. To acheive that I am using the below command:

```
systemctl is-active --quiet mongod
```

This does the job as expected. But it's possible my script will run on systems that do not have systemd, so I am interested in knowing whether there is a more portable way to do this.

Comment: Can you assume the name of the service will be the same? I mean, will the service always be named `mongod` on all systems?

Comment: @terdon Yes that we can assume.

Comment: If the ultimate goal is to ensure the service is running, you could start it without checking — sensible service managers will only start a service if it’s not already running.

Comment: @Stephen Hmm that's a good point. I'll check if mongod also handle that internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not perfect, but will work on many systems. Note that the `pgrep` approach is suboptimal since the name might be slightly different, or you might pass a name that is a substring of another name, but it's a start.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

if systemctl is-active --quiet "$1"  > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "Running! (systemctl)"
elif service "$1" status  2>&1 | grep -Eq 'is running|: active (running)'; then
  echo "Running! (service)"
elif pgrep "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
  echo "Running (pgrep)"
else
  echo "Not running"
fi
```

Save that as `checkIfRunning` and run it like this:

```
checkIfRunning mongod
```

Comment: Oh this looks clean approach. But still we are parsing the output right ? Do you think it's not a problem ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto no, I think it is absolutely a problem :) But I can't think of any way to avoid that if you need to go for portability.

Comment: Hmm thought same.  :)  What do you think about the way I mentioned in my question ? Is it better than your approach ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto what do you mean? I do the exact same thing as you have in your question here. The others are only executed if the first one fails.

Comment: @Zanna d'oh! Of course we shouldn't redirect both streams. Total PEBKAC there, thanks. I got carried away by the others. And good point about the non-systemd `service` output, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no one, portable way of achieving that. But many current Linux distributions have old, legacy `service` command that behaves as a proxy to `systemctl` if run on systemd powered OS.

So you can run the command like this:

```
# service sshd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status sshd.service
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-02-20 12:16:17 UTC; 1 weeks 2 days ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
 Main PID: 3388 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─3388 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```